# How to make Ionic React implementation respect UI = f(state)?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, state, web-component, stenciljs

Ionic React seems not respecting UI = f(state).

I started an application with
`ionic start ionic-tests tabs --type react`
import `IonCheckbox` from `@ionic/react` and used with `<IonCheckbox checked />`, the expected behavior while clicking is keep checked, but the checkbox was toggling...

**Is it the Ionic purpose? There is any way to ensure Ionic React UI as state function?**

Ionic uses **stencil** (web-components) and a layer (called output targets) to solve some connection problems with React. By investigating the code I saw about the `@Prop` decorator with the `mutability` option, but it seems doesn't work (so what is the point about the mutability option?).

Answer (score 0):

manage state

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState<boolean>(true);
```

render

```
<IonCheckbox
  checked={checked}
  onIonChange={(e: any) => setChecked(e.detail.checked)}
></IonCheckbox>
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/checkbox

Comment: I'm sorry but seems that you didn't understand. The point is that ionic components aren't respecting UI = f(state), you just show me how to control the state by using react, and that is not what I expect, but how to ensure that Ionic components will respect any state (checked={true} included?)?